# How assign names to vectors, if they all belong to a list?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list

```
test_list = list(foo = c( "a","b","c"), bar = c("First", "Second"))
test_list
# $foo
# [1] "a" "b" "c" 
# $bar
# [1] "First" "Second"
```

I want to assign names to each element of vector, which I get from levels of data frame

```
annotation = data.frame(foo = factor(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,1))),
                        bar = factor(c(rep('Male',2), rep('Female',4)) ))
# foo     bar
#   1    Male
#   1    Male
#   1  Female
#   2  Female
#   2  Female
#   3  Female
```

I can extract the levels as follows:

```
lapply(annotation, levels)
```

I can assign names one-by-one:

```
names(test_list$foo) <- levels(annotations$foo)
```

However, as I have much longer list in reality, I'd like to vectorize naming procedure. Number of columns in data frame matches exactly number of elements in the list; number of levels of each factor matches exactly number of elements in vectors, which are elements of the list.

How can I do that without going into loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to assign names to `list` elements of `test_list` by the `levels` of corresponding columns of `annotation`.

```
test_list <- Map(setNames, test_list, lapply(annotation, levels))
```